# Changing to superuser failed, but root access. (Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, authentication

i am running Ubuntu 12.04, relatively fresh, only samba 4.2 with dependencies installed.
After changing to root, there's is warning "Access is denied", but then Access is given:

```
adminuser@pc:~$ sudo su
Password: 
Access is denied
root@pdc:/home/admiuser# dmesg                                                                                                                                                                                                          
[   13.793551] type=1400 audit(1384167002.630:12): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/sbin/dhclient" pid=1194 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.794255] type=1400 audit(1384167002.630:13): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/NetworkManager/nm-dhcp-client.action" pid=1194 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.794648] type=1400 audit(1384167002.630:14): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/connman/scripts/dhclient-script" pid=1194 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.801483] type=1400 audit(1384167002.638:15): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=1195 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.802318] type=1400 audit(1384167002.638:16): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1195 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.808872] type=1400 audit(1384167002.646:17): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/ntpd" pid=1196 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   13.829593] type=1400 audit(1384167002.666:18): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" name="/usr/sbin/tcpdump" pid=1198 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   15.213985] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process (658) killed by TERM signal
```

There have been some changes in Authentication for Samba4 - PDC AC:

```
   # cat /etc/nsswitch.conf
   #It should look like:
   passwd:         compat winbind
   group:          compat winbind
   shadow:         compat
   # Configuring PAM in /etc/pam.d/common*
    -auth
       # add:
       auth    sufficient                      pam_winbind.so
       # modify:
        auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure use_first_pass

    -account
       #  Add this line before pam_unix.so:
       account sufficient pam_winbind.so
     -session
       #  Add these lines before any other session line:
       session required pam_mkhomedir.so
       session required pam_winbind.so
```

Is this the source of trouble?

Comment: Do you have the same problem if you just run `sudo -i` or `sudo` alone? What's the point of running `sudo su` anyway?

Comment: Try looking at your shell startup files (`.profile`, `.bash-profile`, `.bashrc`, `/etc/profile`, etc.) to see whether the message might be coming from one of them.

Comment: `sudo -i` did the job without warnings/errors. thanks terdon! `sudo su` seems then just to be a miss-learned behaviour to switch to root. root's `.profile` contains `mesg n` the other recommanded files seem default...

Answer (score 1):

Authentication failed, but root failed to access the user's homefolder.  (You did not include the - to tell su to load the superuser's account.)  If you use `sudo su -`, OR change to a folder that root has permissions to before executing `su`, you should not get the error.  As for best practice, the only time you need to su to root in modern systems is if you need to browse around inside folders where only root can go.